# AS3 - Solve a typed in equation

Tags: actionscript-3, math

I want to be able to type in an equation in a text field and then get an answer as if I'd typed it in code.

The equation could be anything from 1+1 to (4*2*(6-4))/2 etc.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks very much.

Comment: No, there's no eval() in AS3. What you can do is pass the expression to Javascript through ExternalInterface and let the JavaScript engine handle the calculation for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use math equation parser for as3 first from google result [math parser](http://www.flashandmath.com/intermediate/mathparser/mp1.html)

Comment: Thanks. I searched through loads of links for just as3 equation parser:/